# How do I remove specific whitespace inside xml tag in Sublime Text?

Tags: regex, boost, sublimetext3

I have a file with some xml tags that follow specific patterns (Name and Props are placeholders)

```
<Name id="mod:Name"/>
<Prop1 Name id="mod:object.Prop1 Name"/>
<Prop1 Prop2 Name id="mod:object.Prop1 Prop2 Name"/>
<Prop1 Prop2 Prop3 Name id="mod:object.Prop1 Prop2 Prop3 Name"/>
```

I am looking for regex to remove whitespace from portion before the "id=..."

### **How this should look**

```
<Name id="mod:Name"/>
<Prop1Name id="mod:object.Prop1 Name"/>
<Prop1Prop2Name id="mod:object.Prop1 Prop2 Name"/>
<Prop1Prop2Prop3Name id="mod:object.Prop1 Prop2 Prop3 Name"/>
```

I have seen the `(\S+)\s(?=\S+\s+)` example with the substitution being just `\1` but that removes all the spaces except the last one and doesn't leave a space before the id=

```
<Name id="mod:Name"/>
<Prop1Name id="mod:object.Prop1 Name"/>
<Prop1Prop2Name id="mod:object.Prop1Prop2 Name"/>
<Prop1Prop2Prop3Name id="mod:object.Prop1Prop2Prop3 Name"/>
```

I tried something like

`^((\S+)*)\s((\S+)*)\s((\S+)*)\s((\S+)*)\s(?=id)`

But that gave me catastrophic backtracking

Not sure if it helps but Sublime uses Boost regex

First question on The Stack so any improvements on question would be welcome

Thank you

This seems to work

`^(?|((\S+))\s|((\S+)\s(\S+))\s|((\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s))(id=.*)`

with replace of `$2$3$4 $5`

Thanks for the advice

Comment: Can you use a language like JavaScript? You cannot do that using pure regex *(unless applying a regex several times on the string)* .. But if you use a language like Javascript, you can use `.replace` and `callback` to do what you need.

Comment: Can you provide an example how it should be afterwards?

Comment: The second code block is how result should look i'll edit and highlight

Comment: Thanks for the advise @Shafizadeh what was that regex you posted again

Comment: You can *easily* do this in SublimeText. Not with `^(?|((\S+))\s|((\S+)\s(\S+))\s|((\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s))(id=.*)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is there a doc that shows how? The above worked but it is ugly.

Comment: I am adding the explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct regex for removing all whitespaces before the `id` attribute will be

```
(?:<\w+|(?!^)\G)\K\s+(\w+)(?=[^<>]*\bid=")
```

Replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD3fL1/1).

The regex uses the `\G` operator (matches the location after the last successful match if restricted with `(?!^)` lookahead) and the `\K` operator that discards the text that was matched by the pattern so far.

Breakdown:

- `(?:<\w+|(?!^)\G)\K` - match `<` followed with 1+ alphanumeric or underscore characters or the end of the last successful match and omit the text found
- `\s+` - match 1+ whitespace symbols
- `(\w+)` - match and capture into Group 1 one or more alphanumeric or underscore characters (we'll later use a `$1` backreference to restore this consumed text in the result)
- `(?=[^<>]*\bid=")` - only go on matching spaces followed with alphanumerics until it finds `id=` as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary) *but inside the tag* (due to the `[^<>]*` matching zero or more characters other than `<` and `>`).

A [faster alternative](https://regex101.com/r/rD3fL1/3) (to replace with empty string):

```
(?:<|(?!^)\G)\w+\K\s+(?!id=)
```

This regex matches the `<` or the end of the last successful match, then one or more word characters, then `\K` will omit the whole text from the match, and only 1 or more whitespaces will be matched (if not followed with `id=` due to the negative lookahead `(?!id=)`) in the end - and they will be removed.

Comment: Elegant and efficient...what do the \G and \K do? @@WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I have described them right before the `Breakdown`. Note that `\G` matches the start of string and the end of the last successfull match, that is why it must be used with `(?!^)`. But I see you can also use a faster `(?:<|\G)\w+\K\s+(?!id=)`. I will update.

Comment: Awesome that is some regex-fu... Thanks for the answer and breakdown

Comment: So is the addition of the (?!^) to \G more correct/necessary? Seem to work without as well @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: That restriction is logical. If you know for sure that there will be no match at the beginning of the string first, use plain `\G`. I believe your input allows to omit `(?!^)`.

Comment: Btw, I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614478/how-to-execute-a-capturing-group-multiple-times) is almost the same with question above. If you like, write an answer under that. That's interesting for me because all professional people told doing that is impossible using pure-regex, anyway if you have a pure-regex solution, I really like to see it ..

Comment: That one is for JS, and JS regex is much poorer than PCRE/Boost regex.

Comment: Is there a better one for Boost? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @jophish: Please define *better*: more precise (then, provide a test case/requirement), more robust (not sure there can be any if you want a 1-regex solution), with a lookbehind (no, Boost does not support infinite width lookbehind)?