# How to execute a capturing group multiple times?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
var str = "some text start:anything can be here some other text";
```

And here is expected result:

```
//=> some text start:anythingcanbehere some other text
```

In other word, I'm trying to remove all white spaces between a specific range of such a string.

---

Also Here is what I have tried:

```
(start:)(?:(\S+)(\s+))(.*)(?= some)
```

[It works](https://regex101.com/r/wB9eR9/2) as well, but I should execute it several times to achieve expected result .. How can I use `\1+` in my regex to run it several times?

Comment: Use the `g` modifier.

Comment: Where is your Javascript code?

Comment: @Barmar [`g` modifier doesn't work](https://regex101.com/r/wB9eR9/3), I tested it before posting my question

Comment: @Barmar I don't want any javascript code. All I want is *How do I use `\1+` to execute a capturing group multiple times, in this case this capturing group `(?:(\S+)(\s+))`*

Comment: @stack: You need javascript if you want to run it multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do what you want with a simple regexp replace, because a capture group can only capture one string -- there's no looping. Javascript allows you to provide a function as the replacement, and it can perform more complex operations on the captured strings.

```js
var str = "some text start:anything can be here some other text";
var newstr = str.replace(/(start:)(.*)(?= some)/, function(match, g1, g2) {
  return g1 + g2.replace(/ /g, '');
});
alert(newstr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `replace` with a callback:

```
var repl = str.replace(/(start:.*?)(?= some\b)/, function(_, $1) { 
     return $1.replace(/\s+/g, ''); });
//=> some text start:anythingcanbehere some other text
```

Comment: You're missing the space before `some`, so you'll get `heresome` in the result.