# Replace/remove white space inside XML tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

Lets take the following XML for an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<USER>
    <FIRST NAME>John</FIRST NAME>
    <LAST NAME>Johnson</LAST NAME>
    <ADDRESS>Johnson Street</ADDRESS>
</USER>
```

How can I remove/replace white spaces inside the tags using JavaScript?
This is how the output should look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<USER>
    <FIRSTNAME>John</FIRSTNAME>
    <LASTNAME>Johnson</LASTNAME>
    <ADDRESS>Johnson Street</ADDRESS>
</USER>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove specific whitespace inside xml tag in Sublime Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613715/how-do-i-remove-specific-whitespace-inside-xml-tag-in-sublime-text)

Comment: @Cerbrus I am aware of this, just wanted to make the question simple as possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this simple approach

```js
var xmlStr = `
<USER>
    <FIRST NAME>John</FIRST NAME>
    <LAST NAME>Johnson</LAST NAME>
    <ADDRESS>Johnson Street</ADDRESS>
</USER>
`;

function removeSpaceFromXMLTag( input )
{
   //return input.replace(/<(\/){0,1}[\w\s]+>/g, function(match){ return match.replace( /\s+/, "" ) });
   return input.replace(/<(\/)?[\w\s]+>/g, function(match){ return match.replace( /\s+/, "" ) });
}

console.log( removeSpaceFromXMLTag( xmlStr ) );
```

**Explanation**

`/<(\/){0,1}[\w\s]+>/g` matches *xml* tags, *replacer* function will remove space `\s` from all those matches.

Comment: Thanks :) This works for me.

Comment: Instead of `{0,1}`, just use `?`